# How to change random domains to a simple domain using Notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++, find-and-replace, replacement

I have a file with a random domains like this:

```
    host-name                           estkowjf.tradicebk.cz
    domain-key                          smtp,*,/home/pmta/keys/dkim.pem
</virtual-mta>
    host-name                           itaquearuem.tradicebk.cz
    domain-key                          smtp,*,/home/pmta/keys/dkim.pem
</virtual-mta>
    host-name                           inventorecnjof.tradicebk.cz
    domain-key                          smtp,*,/home/pmta/keys/dkim.pem
```

I need to replace xxxx.tradicebk.cz with a simple domain like so:

```
    host-name                         mydomain.com
    domain-key                          smtp,*,/home/pmta/keys/dkim.pem
</virtual-mta>
    host-name                           mydomain.com
    domain-key                          smtp,*,/home/pmta/keys/dkim.pem
</virtual-mta>
    host-name                           mydomain.com
    domain-key                          smtp,*,/home/pmta/keys/dkim.pem
```

How I can do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `host-name\h+\K\S+`
- Replace with: `mydomain.com`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
host-name       # literally
\h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\S+             # 1 or more non-space characters
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

`[a-z]+.tradicebk.cz`

[image]

Comment: This will only work for the domain `tradicebk.cz` but, as stated in question `I have a file with a random domains`

Comment: Yep,just because he said in the middle of his question `I need to replace xxxx.tradicebk.cz `